# is it possible to have two Laravel php web sites using a single mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I would like to have two php Laravel sites connecting to the same MySQL database, all in the same server?

- One site has portfolios from job seekers who login to create/update
  resumes.
- The second site is for employers that post job openings    data. I
  want to match the job seekers to the open job openings, and    job
  openings to job seekers.

Is it possible?
if so, are there any security risks?
Thanks,
MG

Comment: Yes, definitely possible. Literally just connect to the same database. You can also connect to remote databases (on another server). The security risks are only within the code you write, it's no different than a regular website -> database connection that you might write. If they were on separate servers I'd probably suggest writing an API to handle communications between the two (mainly because they're useful to have and fun to write).

Comment: yes it can be done. you can use table prefix if you want to separate site data check this [Configuration docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database#read-write-connections) for more information

Comment: ^ I would assume the purpose of them sharing the same DB is so they can _share_ site data.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that this could cause problems if you're using migrations to manage the database structure, as both sites will try to store their migration records in the same migrations table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is possible. Note that risks is for the developer: it should take more attention when design the app and, in order to avoid conflicts in DB operations (CRUD operation) he may use database's views and transactions. I suggest him to use a solid ORM library that sometimes "saves  the life" in this critical coding situation. See doctrine per PHP, it is one of the best.

Comment: @AndréDaniel in this case, use it properly Maurice G! :)